# changing row background in Dojo Datagrid from dynamic data

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo, event-handling

The topic of changing the Dojo DataGrid row background has been previously discussed on this board as well as the Dojo documentation, which gives a full example (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html).

My issue is a little bit different. I need to change the background color of the rows based on a common field - let's call it 'CityId'. If two rows have the same CityId, then they should have the same background. Note that this question is not concerned with the grouping nor ordering of the data in the grid, but only with the changing of the row style for adjacent rows sharing a common ID field.

The two main paths for this issue involve either hooking into the 'onStyleRow' event or the private '_onFetchComplete' event.

Here's my onStyleRow attempt:

```
var idx = 0;
var prevId = 0;
function myStyleRow(row) {
    var item = grid.getItem(row.index);
    if(item) {
        var currId = store.getValue(item, "CityId", null);
        if ( !!currId ) {

            if ( prevId != currId ) {
                prevId = currId;
                idx++;
            }

            if ( idx%2 == 0 ) {
                row.customStyles += 'background-color:#FFF000;';
            } else {
                //row.customStyles += 'background-color:#000;';
            }
        }
    }
    grid.focus.styleRow(row);
    grid.edit.styleRow(row);
}
```

which gets called during the grid creation among other parameters

```
grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({onStyleRow:myStyleRow});
```

The reason why this approach is unstable is because the onStyleRow event gets triggered on mouse hover, causing the rows to be re-painted due to the prevId value. I would like to know whether/how I could disable onStyleRow from triggering on mouse hovers. This would solve my issue.

In the _onFetchComplete approach, I am stuck trying to find a way to access grid rows. Here's my code:

```
var idx = 0;
var prevId = 0;
grid.connect(grid, '_onFetchComplete', function() {
    // wait until everything is loaded
    for (var i in grid._pending_requests) {
        if (grid._pending_requests[i]) {
           return;
        }
    }


    // parse through row data
    for ( var j=0; j < grid.rowCount; j++) {
        var item = grid.getItem(j);
        if(item) {
            var currId = store.getValue(item, "CityId", null);
            if ( !!currId ) {

                if ( prevId != currId ) {
                    prevId = currId;
                    idx++;
                }

                if ( idx%2 == 0 ) {
                    row.customStyles += 'background-color:#FFF000;';
                } else {
                    //row.customStyles += 'background-color:#000;';
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is obviously a work in progress as there are two missing points: a way to iterate through the grid's rows (grid.rowCount does not work properly) and a way to fetch the grid's rows in order to apply the custom styles. I could not find something like grid.getRow() to address the issue.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure which Version of dojo do you use? Possibly it would solve the Problem to call the grid.on('StyleRow',myStyleRow); Vers.1.9 / dojo.connect('grid','onStyleRow',myStyleRow); event after defining the grid and disconnect the onMouseover for the whole Grid at the same time. Regards

Comment: i have taken this approach - but with similar (unstable) results:


dojo.connect(grid, 'onStyleRow', this, function (row) {
     var item = grid.getItem(row.index);
     ...
});

Comment: How would I disconnect the onMouseover from the grid?

Comment: Have a look here - the link explains how you can disconnect the mouseevent: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/disconnect.html?highlight=disconnect#id2

Comment: I have tried multiple attempts to remove the mouse events from the grid, but nothing worked. Do you have an example? Also, everything I see on the web involves hiding the grid background on mouseover events, but they do not disable the events; they use CSS to alter the format and that's not what I was looking for.

Comment: Made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/g4mnm/ Here I've disconnected the onMouseOver for the Grid.

Comment: Hey MiBrock, thanks for your effort in creating the fiddle! I see what you are trying to do there. You are creating an event handler and then removing it from the grid. However, when I mouse-over the grid elements, I can still see the background change. This is due to the onStyleRow event, which runs by default on mouseover.

Therefore, I wonder if the best way involves extending the onStyleRow event - for only one use; I don't know how this would happen - or finding a way to disconnect the mouseover from the entire grid (bypassing the onStyleRow calls altogether).

Comment: Ok, I got around the issue. Will post solution shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code:

```
var idx = 0;
var prevId = 0;
var passing = {};
var color = {};
dojo.connect(grid, 'onStyleRow', this, function (row) {
    var item = grid.getItem(row.index);
    if(item) {
        var currId = store.getValue(item, "CityId", null);
        if ( !passing[currId] ) {
            passing[currId] = true;

            if ( prevId != currId ) {                       
                prevId = currId;
                idx++;
            }

            if ( idx%2 == 0 ) {
                row.customStyles += 'background-color:#FFF000;';
                color[currId] = 'background-color:#FFF000;';
            } else {
                row.customStyles += 'background-color:#F2F7F7;';
                color[currId] = 'background-color:#F2F7F7;';
            }
        } else {
            row.customStyles += color[currId];
        }
    }
});
```

The 'passing' object is used to mark the first pass through the rows - this point is important because the 'prevId' value is updated correctly. The code works well with multiple calls to get more data into the grid because 'prevId' maintains its integrity. The 'color' object holds the values recorded for row backgrounds. This is needed because the onStyleRow event is called on mouseover, which implies the need to re-paint every time. I hope this helps someone else as well.